# How to show popular hashtag(#) in post table?

Tags: php, mysql

How to show popular hashtag(#) in post table?

I have 1 table post = tb_post

```
post_id | post           | uid
1       | blabla #one    | 01
2       | wew #two       | 01
3       | nice #one      | 02
4       | great #one     | 02
5       | excellent #one | 01
```

-

1. How can I count that hashtag?
2. In that example We know that #one will be the top hashtag. How to show just top #hashtag <-- Just hashtag not include another text. Example:

   ```
   TOP HASHTAG : #one
   ```

My query so far:

```
SELECT DISTINCT post
FROM tb_post
WHERE post LIKE '%#%'
GROUP BY post
```

Comment: Is there only one hashtag in each `post`?

Comment: It depends on user update the post. So I can't say it just only one hashtag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **I accidentally clicked on post the answer. Can the downvotes wait until I finish?**

In PHP, get all the values of `post` in an array, so you will have:

```
Array (
    blabla #one
    wew #two
    nice #one
    great #one
    excellent #one
)
```

Now, join all the array items using `implode(" ", $posts)`, that gives you a string:

```
blabla #one wew #two nice #one great #one excellent #one
```

Split using `explode(" ", $posts)`. Now, check for the values that start with `#`. Add them as an array index and increase the count! Now, you have the code for increasing the count! You can now do this:

```
<?php
$posts = explode(" ", "blabla #one wew #two nice #one great #one excellent #one");
$rank = array();
foreach ($posts as $post)
  if (strpos("#", $post))
    if (!isset($rank[$post]))
      $rank[$post] = 1;
    else
      $rank[$post]++;
?>
```

Or even you can use the function `array_count_values($hashes)` by doing this way:

```
<?php
$posts = explode(" ", "blabla #one wew #two nice #one great #one excellent #one");
$hashes = array();
foreach ($posts as $post)
  if (strpos("#", $post))
    $hashes[] = $post;
?>
```

And now use the `array_sort()` or something to sort the array by descending order and use it for ranking!

> **Downvoters, can you please check and revert those?**

Comment: How does that tell you the most popular hashtag?

Comment: Maybe use `array_count_values` instead of counting them yourself?

Comment: @Barmar Check this out!

Comment: @PraveenKumar Nice answer. I've reverted my downvote (downvoted before the edit)